# AWS graphql does not update

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify

I have this query here:

```
export const econStatusUpdate = (
  groupRequestId: string,
  status: AnforderungEconStatusT
) => {
  console.log(status);
  return axios({
    url: envs.graphqlApiEndpoint!,
    method: "post",
    headers: {
      "x-api-key": envs.graphqlKey!,
    },
    data: {
      query: print(gql(updateGrouprequest)),
      variables: {
        input: {
          id: groupRequestId,
          [status]: true,
        },
      },
    },
  }).then((res) => console.log(res?.data.data));
};
```

And this is how the update looks like:

```
export const updateGrouprequest = /* GraphQL */ `
  mutation UpdateGrouprequest(
    $input: UpdateGrouprequestInput!
    $condition: ModelGrouprequestConditionInput
  ) {
    updateGrouprequest(input: $input, condition: $condition) {
      id
      requesterId
      groupId
      accepted
      message_received
      consent_granted
      get_degree
      createdAt
      updatedAt
      _version
      _deleted
      _lastChangedAt
    }
  }
`;
```

For some reason this does not update it. It also throws no error. My response what i get is always:

```
get_degree
{
  updateGrouprequest: {
    id: '327647e7-c267-4514-ba0e-5bb7fbefe586',
    requesterId: 'b54807ef-3b53-42ee-a559-0c1042d7a121',
    groupId: '32cdcbe8-646d-4680-bb64-8172452a46ca',
    accepted: false,
    message_received: false,
    consent_granted: false,
    get_degree: false,
    createdAt: '2022-06-29T18:16:31.766Z',
    updatedAt: '2022-06-29T18:16:31.766Z',
    _version: 17,
    _deleted: null,
    _lastChangedAt: 1656527657777
  }
}
```

Only the time and version changes, what i am i doing wrong?

Here is also my graphql schema:

```
type Grouprequest
  @model
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: private }, { allow: public, provider: apiKey }]) {
  id: ID!
  requesterId: ID!
  groupId: ID!
  accepted: Boolean @default(value: "false")

  message_received: Boolean @default(value: "false")
  consent_granted: Boolean @default(value: "false")
  get_degree: Boolean @default(value: "false")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to increase the `_version`.You either do it manually or automatic. I do it with `Date.now()`

```
export const econStatusUpdate = (
  groupRequestId: string,
  status: AnforderungEconStatusT
) => {
  console.log(status);
  return axios({
    url: envs.graphqlApiEndpoint!,
    method: "post",
    headers: {
      "x-api-key": envs.graphqlKey!,
    },
    data: {
      query: print(gql(updateGrouprequest)),
      variables: {
        input: {
          id: groupRequestId,
          [status]: true,
          _version: Date.now()
        },
      },
    },
  }).then((res) => console.log(res?.data.data));
};
```